# Building jersey example is failing

Tags: java, maven, jersey

Sorry for this question, but I couldn't find anything similiar to this in the web, so here we go:
I am trying to install jersey as follows :

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp-DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false-DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service-webapp -Dpackage=com.example-DarchetypeVersion=2.22.1
```

It's from their website for an example project. This starts to execute, so JAVA_HOME and mvn are set up properly. But as soon as the console states "Generating Project in Batch mode",  it fails with a "Build Failure", Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin.... The desired archetype does not exist. I can upload a screenshot of the console log if needed.

Comment: I don't know if it was a copy-paste mistake or your actual command, but there needs to be space here `-webapp-Darchetype`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [url](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#new-from-archetype) I could correctly generate the archetype whith the following step.

1-First I create an empty maven project
then I modified the pom file like this

```
  <groupId>fr.toto</groupId>
  <artifactId>tata</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>snapshot-repository.java.net</id>
    <name>Java.net Snapshot Repository for Maven</name>
    <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
</repositories>
```

Then I run the following command inside the root dir of the empty project I created at step 1 :

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
-DgroupId=fr.cnamts -DartifactId=tata -Dpackage=fr.cnamts \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.22.1
```

And voilà it works!

Comment: Thanks for that, I will try this!

Comment: Okay I was able to create the empty maven project, but the next part is still failing for me

Comment: Mhm okay, I changed <packaging>jar to <packaging>pom and it worked, thanks!